# How to remove a foreign constrain of a DROPPED table (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have dropped a table but the record of a foreign constrain is left behind in the **INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN** and **INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS** tables...

The table name **was** `procesos`

The record in `INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS`  is

```
ID|FOR_COL_NAME|REF_COL_NAME|POS
```

DBname/fk_procesos_hv1|id_hv|id_hv

And the record in `INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN` is

```
ID|FOR_NAME|REF_NAME|N_COLS|TYPE
```

DBname/fk_procesos_hv1|DBname/procesos|DBname/hv|1|48

I've created a second table named `procesos2` but when I tried to renamed as `procesos` I got this message "errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" so, How can I remove the foreign constrain of the DROPPED table `procesos`?

Comment: did you try ALTER TABLE `procesos`
 DROP FOREIGN KEY `id_name_fk`;

Comment: yes, but MySQL says the table `procesos`does not exists

Answer (score 0):

First disable foreign key constraints

```
SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0
```

Rename your table to procesos and then remove the constraint.

after that enable constraint again

```
SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1
```

You should chekck if there is also an index set for the table procesos , which also should be removed.

Comment: I'got this message:
#1025 - Error on rename of './DBname/procesos2' to './DBname/procesos' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: The Column for the foreign must be identical in both tables. But the foreign key chekcks should be disbaled.

Comment: Thank you for your time, @nbk.
There is an other error with the referenced table. The referenced table is not showed but its spacetable does (exists)... then I requested to the DB Admin to destroy/create the DB and to restore the last backup... fortunatly we are still in dev fase.
By the way, the error I've got says: #1813 - Tablespace for table '`DBname`.`HV`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT